# windows can't run application stored on network drive

Tags: windows, mac-osx, mac-osx-server, server-message-block

I have a windows desktop PC (windows 10 insider preview, if it matters)

I also have a mac on which i've enabled SMB file sharing. I created a test folder, i accessed said folder on my PC, and mounted it as a drive letter. (Z:\)

I installed itunes using windows installer on the drive. However when i tried to run it, a dialog box popped up asking me if im sure that i want to run the .exe, and after i pressed run a second dialog box popped up saying that "windows cannot access \ipadress\folder\itunes.exe"

What do I have to do to make windows run the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you don't speak about authorization, I assume that you have not set the execute autorization on your shared folder. Check if your authorization on your Mac (read, execute, modify, etc.) are correctly set.